# React big-calendar events not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to show events from api on react-big-calendar but for some reason the events don't show up on the calendar. I get the events to console but they don't show up in calendar. 
Here is my **Calendar.js** component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer} from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

export default function TrainingCalendar() {
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

    const [trainings, setTrainings] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      getTrainings()
    });

    const getTrainings = () => {
      fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/gettrainings')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setTrainings(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    const events = trainings.map((training) => 
        training =
        {
          allDay: 'false',
          title: training.activity,
          start: training.date,
          end: training.date + moment().add(training.duration, 'minutes'),
          resource: training.customer.firstname
        }
    );
    console.log('events:', events);

    return (
        <Calendar 
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        allDayAccessor='allDay'
        titleAccessor='title'
        resourceAccessor='resource'
        startAccessor='start'
        endAccessor='end'
        views={['month', 'week', 'day']}
        style={{height: 450}}
        />
    )
}
```

What should I do to get the events to show up?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems here:

1. To use useeffect like componentdidmount add an empty dependency array ie.

   useEffect(() => {
           getTrainings()
       }, []);
2. Event end and event start should be dates not strings so do something like:

   start: moment(training.date).toDate(),
3. Moment add doesn't work like a mathematical operator in javascript so that line should be something like:

   ```
       end: moment(training.date).add(training.duration, 'minutes').toDate(),
   ```

So all the code will look something like:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

export default function TrainingCalendar() {
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

    const [trainings, setTrainings] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getTrainings()
    }, []);

    const getTrainings = () => {
        fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/gettrainings')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setTrainings(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    const events = trainings.map((training: any) =>
        training =
        {
            allDay: 'false',
            title: training.activity,
            start: moment(training.date).toDate(),
            end: moment(training.date).add(training.duration, 'minutes').toDate(),
            resource: training.customer.firstname
        }
    );
    console.log('events:', events);

    return (
        <Calendar
            localizer={localizer}
            events={events}
            allDayAccessor='allDay'
            titleAccessor='title'
            resourceAccessor='resource'
            startAccessor='start'
            endAccessor='end'
            views={['month', 'week', 'day']}
            style={{ height: 450 }}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Not 100% sure if this works becaues I solved it differently after asking my teacher.

Comment: Yes your final code looks very similar to mine. Still not sure why you would call useeffect here without a dependency array? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760842/why-would-we-use-useeffect-without-a-dependency-array

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but you can propably also try what viet-teach wrote here.

Here is how I solved it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer} from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

export default function TrainingCalendar() {
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

    const [trainings, setTrainings] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      getTrainings()
    });

    const getTrainings = () => {
      fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/gettrainings')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setTrainings(data.map((training) =>(
            {
              title: training.activity,
              start: moment.utc(training.date)._d,
              end: moment.utc(training.date).add(trainings.duration, 'minutes')._d,
              resource: training.customer.firstname
            })
          )))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    return (
        <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={trainings}
        resourceTitleAccessor='resource'
        startAccessor='start'
        endAccessor='end'
        views={['month', 'week', 'day']}
        style={{height: 450}}
        />
    )
}
```