# React prop function called after useState set hook kills hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an PostImagesList component that updates when an image is removed. I also send the removed image id to the parent for deletion if the post update is ultimately committed.

I'm trying to understand why a prop function (onRemoveImage) kills the setImages useState hook, unless I remove the same image twice(?) Presently in the parent I am only logging the id sent from the child so nothing is changing with the data.

```
  // <PostImagesList />
  const handleRemoveImage = (e, idx, imageId) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let newFilesArr = [...images];
    newFilesArr.splice(idx, 1);
    setImages(newFilesArr);
    onRemoveImage(imageId); // If I comment this out, the setImages updates correctly
  };
```

images is initially set in PostImagesList in a useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setImages(
      imagesByPostId?.edges
        ? imagesByPostId?.edges
            .filter(Boolean)
            .map((edge) => edge.node)
            .filter(Boolean)
        : [],
    );
};
```

I also tried setting the images in the declaration instead of in a useEffect hook:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState(() => {
  return imagesByPostId?.edges
    ? imagesByPostId?.edges
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map((edge) => edge.node)
        .filter(Boolean)
    : [];
});
```

I want to update the list locally in `<PostImagesList/>`, and send the deleted image id to the parent, but not rerender `<PostImagesList/>`.

Comment: Where do you set the image state? In PostImageList or in the parent?

Comment: @SamiElk In PostImagesList. I initially set it in a useEffect hook from a graphQL prop imagesByPostId. I upaded my post to add this hook.

Comment: See [Why would we use useEffect without a dependency array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760937/16997707) - means useEffect runs on every render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where you declared setImages but if you want to set the initial state you can do like:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(whatever)
```

If you want to set it depending on complex conditions, then you can use React.useReducer instead of React.useState or define initial state like:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => {
  if (itsCool) return "cool";
  else return "not cool";
});
```

If you need to use that useEffect hook and you want to set something at the initial render then you need to pass an empty dependency Array, else you can run into "Maximum update depth exceeded" because setState will call repeatedly. So do it like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setImages(
      imagesByPostId?.edges
        ? imagesByPostId?.edges
            .filter(Boolean)
            .map((edge) => edge.node)
            .filter(Boolean)
        : [],
    );
}, []); // here is the empty dependency array
```

**More about useEffect if you are interested:**

Note that useEffect is not only componentDidMount but also componentDidUpdate, so the callback function you pass will executed on every component-update. If you pass a dependency array the callback function you pass will get executed only when the dependeny (reference) changes. Something like:

```
const { useEffect } = (function() {
  var _dep = null;
  function useEffect(clb, dep) {
    if (_dep === null) {
      _dep = dep;
      clb();
    } else if (_dep !== dep) {
      _dep = dep;
      clb();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  return {
    useEffect
  };
})();

var counter = 1;

const cbk = () => console.log(counter);

useEffect(cbk, counter);
useEffect(cbk, counter); // cbk will not execute
useEffect(cbk, counter); // cbk will not execute
counter++;
useEffect(cbk, counter);
```

to simpily the useEffect funtion we don't pass a dependency array we just pass one dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem is that when I send the deleted image id to the parent, it triggers a rerender of the PostImagesList component which builds the complete image list again, including the deleted image because I don't want to actually delete the image from the db yet. I just want to build an array of deleted image ids in the parent and only delete them from the db if the user "saves" the updated post.

Comment: Yes every update of state or props will rerender the component. I will edit the answer and explain more about useEffect.

Comment: Thank you. I tried removing the `setImage` from the useEffect hook and putting it directly in the declaration, i.e. `const [images, setImages] = useState(()=>{...}` but it didn't help.

Comment: The function you define in the useState, does it return a value?
It has to return a value like `const [images, setImages] = useState(()=>{...; return something}`

Comment: I updated my post with the useState declaration.

Comment: Now you have set the initial value fo images. You can see here that this convention works: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-meadow-nbeew?file=/src/App.tsx

What is right now the problem?

Comment: Is it opensource? I could take a look at if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241338/discussion-between-maziar-b-and-kirk-ross).