# Does multiple setState at once guarantee to be happened at once in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below piece of code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Mycomp = () => {
  const [firstState, setFirstState] = useState(0);
  const [secondState, setSecondState] = useState(0);
  const [thirdState, setThirdState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(thirdState);
    console.log(firstState);
    console.log(secondState);
  }, [thirdState])

  const onClick = () => {
    setThirdState(["something"])
    setFirstState(1)
    setSecondState(2)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mycomp;
```

I have two questions here

1. Is it possible that as I have written `setThirdState` at the first in `onClick` function then it gets called & set the state and call the `useEffect` and I do not get updated `firstState` & `secondState`?
2. Is it good to use array as dependency in `useEffect`. If not, then what is the other option?

Edit: Here is my use case

```
const Mycomponent = () => {
    const [clipcount, setClipcount] = useState(0);
    const [clipsDetails, setClipsDetails] = useState([]);
    const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(1);
    const [socketClipCount, setSocketClipCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
    webhookSocket.on(`livecut${id}`, (data) => {
      setSocketClipCount((socketClipCount) => socketClipCount + 1);
    });
  }, [webhookSocket]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getClips();
    }, [activePage])

    const getClips = async () => {
        const { value } = await getAllClips({
            limit: clipLimit,
            pageNo: activePage,
            sort: { _id: -1 },
        });
        if (value?.success) {
            setClipcount(value.totalLength);
            setClipsDetails([...clipsDetails, ...value?.clips]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="custom-generated-clips styled-scroll">
            {socketClipCount && <button onClick={() => {
                setSocketClipCount(0);
                setClipsDetails([]);
                setActivePage(1);
            }}>
                Refresh
            </button>}
            <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={clipsDetails?.length}
                hasMore={clipsDetails?.length < clipcount ? true : false}
                next={() => setActivePage(activePage + 1)}
                loader={
                    <div className="InfinitScrollLoadingBottom">
                        <div className="InfinitScrollLoadingBottomText">Loading...</div>
                    </div>
                }
                endMessage={
                    <div className="InfinitScrollEndBottom">
                        <div className="InfinitScrollEndBottomText">
                            {clipsDetails?.length > 4 ? "You've reached End!" : ""}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                // pullDownToRefreshThreshold={limit}
                scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
            >
                {myData}
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Mycomponent;
```

So here I am getting `clipDetails` and showing it in `Infinite scroll` which is simple thing. Now when I get clips from socket I show the `Refresh` button and refreshing that section by setting `setSocketClipCount(0);setClipsDetails([]);setActivePage(1);` but it does not set the state for the `clipDetails` & `socketClipCount` array.

What could be the solution for it? I am using React 18 even batch updating is not working.

It is hard for me to get things because sometimes React official docs says

1. It is not good to club the state like `useState({ state1: "", state2: "" })`
2. React 18 supports batch update still the above code does not work.

Comment: https://dev.to/this-is-learning/automatic-batching-in-react-18-273h

Comment: 1) Yes, so [better use a single state](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#group-related-state). While updates in a click handler are batched, your code should not rely on that 2) For logging the state, you want no dependencies at all - or even no effect at all. But it's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: @Bergi #1. Then what is the solution to get all the setState updated values at once? #2. It is just an example, I want to perform some action on that dependency.

Comment: @Profer see the link. Use a single `useState` with an object.

Comment: @Bergi The link `super` has sent says react 18 supports batch state updates!

Comment: I'm in agreement with Bergi in that it's unclear what you are really trying to do for these to be your questions. I would expect all the enqueued state updates in `onClick` to be processed prior to any component rerender and subsequent `useEffect` hook callback being called. You should just about *always* use a dependency array (*with appropriate dependencies*) on React hooks that utilize them. Do you have a more tangible [mcve] for what you are doing?

Comment: @DrewReese oops I forgot to add `thirdState` as dependency array. Updated the question. Now does it make sense?

Comment: Not really, but I guess the answer to "Does multiple setState at once guarantee to be happened at once in react hooks?" is "yes" when all the enqueued updates happen in a synchronous function, i.e. because React generally batches updates where it can as a performance optimization. The `useEffect` hook is ***technically*** missing `firstState` and `secondState` as dependencies since they are external references.

Comment: @Profer "*react 18 supports batch state updates!*" - doesn't matter. It's still [bad engineering to design component state shapes so that they can even represent inconsistent state](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-contradictions-in-state).

Comment: Note that it's easier to answer 1 question instead of 2 at once _(I would have liked to write an answer, but 2 answers is too much effort)_. I agree that it's conceptually not _guaranteed_ that all update consistently, even if it actually works. There would be different solutions for different use cases. If they depend on each other, they should be coupled (e.g. same object) or should use "dependencies" to update each other.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it does not set the state for the `clipDetails` & `socketClipCount` array"? The state updates are enqueued so I'd fully expect them to be processed and the states updated. Are they actually updating and there's some other issue?

Comment: @DrewReese when I click on the `onClick` of Refresh button and setting `setSocketClipCount(0); setClipsDetails([]); setActivePage(1);
` then `activePage` changes to `1` and `useEffect` gets called but `clipDetails` does not set to `[]` and `socketClipCount` to `0`

Comment: How exactly are you verifying that these states are not being updated? Setting the `activePage` triggers `getClips` to be called, which potentially updates both the `clipcount ` and `clipsDetails ` states, the two states you coincidentally say don't update. Would it be possible for you to create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduced this state updating issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: "*React official docs says [that] it is not good to club the state like `useState({ state1: "", state2: "" })`*" - no they don't?

Comment: Your snippet is missing the definition of `webhookSocket` and `id`, and the effect that registers `webhookSocket.on(`livecut${id}`, …)` needs to return a cleanup function

Comment: `setClipsDetails([...clipsDetails, ...value?.clips]);`, after an `await`, is a problem if `getClips()` is called multiple times concurrently. Use an updater callback instead that you pass to `setClipDetails`

Comment: @Bergi Yes that *after an await, is a problem* It was the issue. Finally I figured it out but what does it mean *Use an updater callback instead that you pass to setClipDetails ?* How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue here is using **`useEffect`** for user actions

both of your usecases are good (according to docs), but only on paper:

- subscribing to `webhookSocket`
- fetching clips

but due to how you rely on setstate and rerenders to react to user action and for example fetch data, your  flow breaks along the way. this, paired with impure functions makes it even harder to trace whats happening.

#### separate your events

we can break it down in two events that are **user triggered**, and two that are triggered either outside of react, or just happen **without any action**.

❌ no `useEffect`

- user clicks refresh
- user triggers infiniteScroll.next

✅ `useEffect`

- new socket message
- initial load

heres what i'd change, to accomplish that:

- for `getClips()` move the implicit dependency on `activePage` to an explicit `page` param. that way you can call it whenever you want with the parameters you need
- run the initial `getClips()` in a run-once `useEffect` (we *should* supply `getClips` as a dependency for `useEffect`, and thus wrap it in `useCallback` to make it stable)
- when appending new `clipsDetails`, dont use a potentially stale value for `clipsDetails` in the spread. `setClipsDetails((prev) => [...prev, ...value?.clips]);` this makes sure it uses the right value.
- when clicking the `refresh` button: refetch data with the currently active page, and reset the "unseen clips" counter.
- when triggering the `next` event in the infinite scroll: load the next page and increment `activePage`.

```
const Mycomponent = () => {
  const [clipcount, setClipcount] = useState(0);
  const [clipsDetails, setClipsDetails] = useState([]);
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(1);
  const [socketClipCount, setSocketClipCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // i'm 99% sure you dont need the webhookSocket instance inside the component scope. unless it dependes on some component state (like a room-id) you should move it outside of the component definition. that way its stable and not required as dependency.
    webhookSocket.on(`livecut${id}`, (data) => {
      setSocketClipCount((socketClipCount) => socketClipCount + 1);
    });
    return () => {
      // unsubscribe from webhookSocket
    };
  }, []);

  const getClips = useCallback(async (page) => {
    const { value } = await getAllClips({
      limit: clipLimit,
      pageNo: page,
      sort: { _id: -1 }
    });
    if (value?.success) {
      setClipcount(value.totalLength);
      setClipsDetails((prev) => [...prev, ...value?.clips]); // use the current value of clipsDetails in the spread
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getClips();
  }, [getClips]);

  return (
    <div className="custom-generated-clips styled-scroll">
      {socketClipCount > 0 && ( // dont use non booleans with `&&` in jsx, as this will render the 0 as text
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            getClips({ page: activePage });
            setSocketClipCount(0);
          }}
        >
          Refresh ({socketClipCount})
        </button>
      )}
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={clipsDetails?.length}
        hasMore={clipsDetails?.length < clipcount} // `? true : false` not needed as this already returns boolean
        next={() => {
          setActivePage(activePage + 1);
          getClips({ page: activePage + 1 });
        }}
        loader={
          <div className="InfinitScrollLoadingBottom">
            <div className="InfinitScrollLoadingBottomText">Loading...</div>
          </div>
        }
        endMessage={
          <div className="InfinitScrollEndBottom">
            <div className="InfinitScrollEndBottomText">
              {clipsDetails?.length > 4 ? "You've reached End!" : ""}
            </div>
          </div>
        }
        // pullDownToRefreshThreshold={limit}
        scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
      >
        {myData}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mycomponent;
```

i've added a few more smaller things as comments. i hope this helps.
i'd highly recommend reading this article in the new react docs, as this helps you prevent error-prone uses of `useEffect`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. what do you use getClips inside a dependency array and why did you use `useCallback` with it?

Comment: when using a function in a `useEffect`, we have to supply the function as a dependency. because the `useEffect` depends on it. (i highly recommend using the eslint plugin `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`)
if we do that, the useEffect will run whenever the value of `getClips` changes. which by default would be on every component render, because the function is defined in the (render) function body. thats why we have to wrap `getClips` in a `useCallback`. this will make sure that the function value only changes when its dependencies change.

Comment: if we didnt need to call `getClips` outside of the `useEffect` i'd move the function definition inside the effect. that we wouldnt have any dependencies at all.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your use case

- **Your getClips useEffect doesn't depend only on activePage but also on
  socketClipCount which is missing in your code**
- **If you wanna set ClipsDetails to an empty array socketClipCount must be equal to 0**

On your refresh click you are having two similar setState (set clipDetails to empty array then getClips executes and set the clipDetails again with the http response) , one after the other and only the last one will take effect

1. setClipsDetails([])
2. setActivePage(1) will trigger the **getClips** effect
3. setClipsDetails([...clipsDetails, ...value?.clips]) is executed inside the effect and it's the change and the one that is painted on your view

**To make your code works you have to add a new dependency (socketClipCount) to getClips effect** and use it to check when the getClips function is executed

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // avoid loading when refreshing or initializing
    if(socketClipCount > 0) {
       getClips();
    }
 }, [activePage, socketClipCount])
```

As a result when you click refresh you will have

- **ClipsDetails** set to an empty array
- **activePage** to 1

If you find that socketClipCount is not changed it's probably changed in the same time here with a new value different from 0

```
useEffect(() => {
 webhookSocket.on(`livecut${id}`, (data) => {
  setSocketClipCount((socketClipCount) => socketClipCount + 1);
 });
}, [webhookSocket]);
```

**May be closing the connection for few seconds when refreshing the open it again would be a good solution**

Comment: "*you are having two similar setState (set clipDetails to empty array the execute the getClips) , one after the other and only the last one will take effect*" - it seems you are missing the `await` in between

Answer (score 1):

> Now when I get clips from socket I show the Refresh button and refreshing that section by setting
>
> ```js
> setSocketClipCount(0);
> setClipsDetails([]);
> setActivePage(1);
> ```
>
> but it does not set the state for the `clipDetails` & `socketClipCount` array.

**It does**.

> Batching is when React groups multiple state updates into a single re-render for better performance. Without automatic batching, we only batched updates inside React event handlers

But since you are updating `activePage` and this latter is included in the `useEffect` dependency array, once the component finishes rerendering, `useEffect` will run, and since the code inside it is updating `clipsDetails` and `clipsDetails` this will make the component rerender again, and it looks like only `activePage` is updated.

So if you want to run `getClips` only on the first mount of the component you have to give an empty dependency array to `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getClips();
},[]);
```

And if you want to execute `getClips()` in some specific cases, not only on the first mount, then you can create another state:

```js
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);
//...
useEffect(() => {
  getClips();
},[trigger]);
```

then each time you want to trigger `getClips()` all you have to do is to update `trigger` :

```
setTrigger(prev => !prev);
```

---

> Is it good to use array as dependency in useEffect. If not, then what is the other option?

It is not about good or bad, it's about the use case.
If you want to trigger the code inside a `useEffect` when the component rerenders and 'something' is different from what it was during the last render, then you include this 'thing' in the dependency array, and if you want `useEffect` to act as the `componentdidmount` (run only when the component is mounted) than you give it an empty dependency array `[]` and if you don't give a dependency array at all, this will make the useEffect hook run on every component rerender.

And if you mean an array inside the dependency array then yes you can, but keep in mind that each time the array is updated the component will rerender  and useEffect will fire (the component only rerenders when the new value of useState is different from the current one) but since two objects are always not equal in javascript, even if the array is updated with the same value this will make the component rerender anyway.

Comment: I don't think OP is really asking to have how the `useEffect` hook dependency array works explained to them. They are asking for a solution to their perceived incorrect state updates, or state not updating as they think it should. Still waiting for them to respond and update their post with better details and what they are expecting the code to do. They've yet to really clearly explain what the problem is.

Comment: please do not use state values to trigger events. this is actually a prime example of what not to do, according to the new react docs: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#sending-a-post-request

Comment: well, the op asked about useEffect dependency array, and even if he didn't, the whole post revolves around not understanding how useEffect works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is better to keep dependency array in useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log("UseEffect is calling..")
console.log(thirdState);
console.log(firstState);
console.log(secondState);

}, [thirdState])

const onClick = () => {
    setThirdState(["something"]);
    console.log("Set Third State..")
    setFirstState(1)
    console.log("Set First State..")
    setSecondState(2)
    console.log("Set Second State..")
  }
```

[image]

If your onClick() function have more than one functions and you need a guarantee to to see the state changes from the firstfunction to consecutive functions, then you can use callback function. since you want first function to get executed in onClick(), what you can do is you can call the second function after setting the required state in the first function.

All about dependency array in useEffect, nice explanation is given on [useEffect dependency array in React.js](https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/useeffect-dependency)

See explanation by nem035 for [explanation on empty dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760937/12319961)